# Setup Rabbitmq consumer in dotnet core by timed background task

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-core, rabbitmq

I try to setup the rabbitmq consumer by **timed background task**, however, it's not always consuming message correctly. **It seems to get message from queue, but does not log the received message correctly.** This seems to be very weird. I guess it's somehow related to the event handler receiving message not executed properly, but I just cannot figure out why.

I do the timed background task as discussed in [Background tasks with hosted services in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/host/hosted-services?view=aspnetcore-3.1&tabs=visual-studio#backgroundservice-base-class) because I want to avoid having a long lived connection. I feel it's more safe to create new connections to queue when needed.

However, when using background service with long lived connection, everything actually works fine so far.

Can someone tell me what's wrong about the following code?

```
// consumer part
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration;
using Microsoft.Extensions.DependencyInjection;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Hosting;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Logging;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using RabbitMQ.Client.Events;

namespace play_mq
{
    public class Program
    {
        public static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            CreateHostBuilder(args).Build().Run();
        }

        public static IHostBuilder CreateHostBuilder(string[] args) =>
            Host.CreateDefaultBuilder(args)
                .ConfigureLogging(logging =>
                {
                    logging.AddConsole();
                })
                .ConfigureServices(services =>
                {
                    services.AddHostedService<MessageListener>();
                });
    }

    public class MessageListener : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IOptions<RabbitOptions> _rabbitOptions;
        private readonly ILogger<MessageListener> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;
        private int executionCount = 0;

        public MessageListener(ILogger<MessageListener> logger, IOptions<RabbitOptions> rabbitOptions)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _rabbitOptions = rabbitOptions;
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "MessageListener is working. Count: {Count}", count);

            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };

            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
                var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
                consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
                {
                    var body = ea.Body;
                    var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
                    _logger.LogInformation($"consume {message}");
                };
                channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
            }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MessageListener is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }

}
```

```
// Sender comes from official example
using System;
using RabbitMQ.Client;
using System.Text;

namespace ConsoleMq
{
    class Send
    {
        public static void Main()
        {
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory() { HostName = "localhost", Port = 14000 };
            using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            {
                channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);

                string message = "Hello World!";
                var body = Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(message);

                channel.BasicPublish(exchange: "", routingKey: "hello", basicProperties: null, body: body);
                Console.WriteLine(" [x] Sent {0}", message);
            }

            Console.WriteLine(" Press [enter] to exit.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 3):

> **It seems to get message from queue, but does not log the received message correctly.**

Reason:

```
channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: true, consumer: consumer);
```

autoAck set to true, It ack positive to a broker before receiving a message. and broker remove it from the queue once it ack +

**Solution**: Instead of Setting ack(true) there(Set auroAck = false), And Ack when you receive message

```
consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
               channel.BasicAck(deliveryTag: ea.DeliveryTag, multiple: false);
               //Other method available for negative ack
            };
```

> I want to avoid having a long lived connection. I feel it's more safe to create new ?connections to queue when needed.

For a better answer to your question, You can check [**MassTransit**(RabbitMQ wrapper)](https://github.com/MassTransit/MassTransit)  code.

And **to receive messages as it publishes**

```
public class MessageListener : IHostedService, IDisposable
    {
        private readonly IOptions<RMQConfig> _rabbitOptions;
        private readonly ILogger<MessageListener> _logger;
        private Timer _timer;
        private int executionCount = 0;
        private readonly IConnection _connection;

        public MessageListener(ILogger<MessageListener> logger, IOptions<RMQConfig> rabbitOptions)
        {
            _logger = logger;
            _rabbitOptions = rabbitOptions;
            var factory = new ConnectionFactory()
            {
                HostName = "localhost"
            };
            _connection = factory.CreateConnection();
        }

        public Task StartAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _timer = new Timer(DoWork, null, TimeSpan.Zero,
                TimeSpan.FromSeconds(5));

            return Task.CompletedTask;

        }

        private void DoWork(object state)
        {
            var count = Interlocked.Increment(ref executionCount);

            _logger.LogInformation(
                "MessageListener is working. Count: {Count}", count);



            // using (var connection = factory.CreateConnection())
            // using (var channel = connection.CreateModel())
            // { 
            var channel = _connection.CreateModel();

            channel.QueueDeclare(queue: "hello", durable: false, exclusive: false, autoDelete: false, arguments: null);
            var consumer = new EventingBasicConsumer(channel);
            consumer.Received += (model, ea) =>
            {
                var body = ea.Body;
                var message = Encoding.UTF8.GetString(body.ToArray());
                _logger.LogInformation($"consume {message}");
            };
            channel.BasicConsume(queue: "hello", autoAck: false, consumer: consumer);
            // }
        }

        public Task StopAsync(CancellationToken cancellationToken)
        {
            _logger.LogInformation("MessageListener is stopping.");

            _timer?.Change(Timeout.Infinite, 0);

            return Task.CompletedTask;
        }

        public void Dispose()
        {
            //Close _connection
            _timer?.Dispose();
        }
    }
```

I faced the same issue a few months back, Hope It will help others.